# When to use bootstrap 4 classes and when to use my own css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie programmer and new to bootstrap 4.

I can style a footer column heading in 2 ways :

In the CSS file like this :

```
.footer-heading-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

or in the HTML file like this using Bootstrap 4 :

```
<p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold"> Heading 1 </p>
```

In terms of code design, maintenance, performance etc is one way better than the other? What should I be considering when making a choice?

I want to try and use the right approach to this thing from the start. So thanks for any advice.

Comment: Optimal/Performance/design: plan and write the code yourself;
Maintenance/easy/quick: use the code someone else wrote (libraries/frameworks);

Comment: I rarely program CSS, but I think it would make sense to use Bootstrap if it's a style only used once. If the style is used multiple times, I'd write my own style

Comment: I use bootstrap on a regular basis, my opinion is, why rewrite something that is already done for you, don't reinvent the wheel. Only write your own CSS if you need to apply a specific style that can not be achieved by bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap basically for layout.
For styling like that use CSS.